# Python - split entries into an array

Tags: python, json, split, strip

I have a JSON response that has a 2 sections I want to run numerical comparisons on. I can get at the values but I am struggling to remove the [] and split the entries with ,. My string looks like this:

```
r = """{
    "eth_btc":{
        "asks":[
            [103.426,0.01],
            [103.5,15],
            [103.504,0.425],
            [103.505,0.1]
        ],
        "bids":[
            [103.2,2.48502251],
            [103.082,0.46540304],
            [102.91,0.99007913],
            [102.83,0.07832332]
        ]
    }
}"""
```

The values are "cost, volume". I need both values, and I want to do numerical comparisons between ASKS and BIDS.

I need to get rid of the [] which is easy, and I would also like to separate the values with SPLIT, but I am having trouble putting them into a LIST. Since the data is already in a dictionary, perhaps I don't need to do all of this but I am unsure how to proceed.

```
j = json.loads(r)
mylist = list()
for item in j['eth_btc']['asks']:
    tempString = str(item).strip('[]')
    mylist.append(tempString.split(','))

print (mylist)
```

The values then need to be turned from strings into numbers.

I appreciate any help getting going on this.

Comment: `j['eth_btc']['asks']` is already a list. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand why you're converting it to a string in the first place.

Comment: Most likely because I don't yet have a command of the language :) I needed to get rid of the [ and ] and .strip seems great for that. .split seemed like a good idea to get each individual value. What I am struggling with is how would I numerically compare the ASKS to BIDS by their first price, then compare the volume for each value and then display a result. If ASK was lower than BID then I want to create a string that informs the user to buy at the ask price but only the volume of the BID price. If there is not enough volume in the ASK price then inform the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you don't have to do anything here, `json` does it for you.

```
import json

j = json.loads(r)
mylist = list()
print j['eth_btc']['asks']
```

Output:

```
[[103.426, 0.01], [103.5, 15], [103.504, 0.425], [103.505, 0.1]]
```

`json` already parse integers and floats in expected type (`int` and `float`). You don't have to re-parse it by hand.

---

If you need to got pairs and do maths on it, do somehting like:

```
for pair in j['eth_btc']['asks']:
    print pair
    print pair[0] * pair[1]
    print '-' * 20
```

Output:

```
[103.426, 0.01]
1.03426
--------------------
[103.5, 15]
1552.5
--------------------
[103.504, 0.425]
43.9892
--------------------
[103.505, 0.1]
10.3505
--------------------
```

Comment: OK - how can I get at each pair separately? I need to do math on 103.426 and 0.01 as separate variables.

Comment: `for pair in j['eth_btc']['asks']:
         print pair[0]+pair[1]`

Comment: Thank you so very much for helping me on my Python journey. I appreciate your kindness.